# Watson Natural Language Classifier: How many example phrases can be provided in one classifier

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

In the documentation of **IBM Watson Natural Language Classifier (NLC)** is written that we pass a `CSV` file with our *phrases* and their responding *classes*.

So my question is: How many phrases/classes or simply said rows can we put in one file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The limit is 20.000 phrases and no more than 3.000 classes, as specified [here](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/natural-language-classifier?topic=natural-language-classifier-using-your-data).

I hope this answer helps you.

Comment: This is for the request length. Please look at the question again. It's asked about the total number of phrases and classes in a NLC instance.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. I've updated the answer.

Comment: That's answered the question. Thank you!